# How to change TextView to multi size in single texview

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

How to change my `textview` size to multi sizes when I select sample in my layout `texview` size should be change like this I need four different sizes, I google it I not found any solution for this so any please help me

here below my screen short

[image]

Comment: you can set text view size in shared preferece that is the option

Comment: change the text size on item selection.

Answer (score 0):

**onClick(event you want), you can change textsize of textview you want programatically**

EX: Do something like

```
radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    text1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,14);
                    text2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,18);
                    text3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,22);
                    text4.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,26);                   
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

you can save selected text size in shared preferece

```
  public void showDialog()
        {
            final CharSequence[] items={"Use device font size","Tiny","Small","Normal","Huge"};
            final CharSequence[] fontSize={"15","10","15","20","25"};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder=   new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Font size");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            int i=     sharedpreference.getInt("position", 0)  ;
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items,i, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    editor.remove("fontsize");
                    editor.remove("position");
                    editor.putFloat("fontsize",Float.parseFloat(fontSize[ which] .toString()));
                    editor.putInt("position", which);
                    editor.commit();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.create();
            builder.show();
        }
```

and  size of textview set dianamically

```
textview.setTextSize(sharedpreference.getFloat("fontsize", 15));
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable named `int size = 12`;

Implement onClick event of `Done` button of dialog interface and get which radio button is selected using if else ladder and set variable value to the size you want accordingly.

then set this size to `TextView` you want using `text.setTextSize(size);`.

It works in my case.